# Why disptach_async() could reduce this kind memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I used Instrument to detect memory leak which found out 5 leaks, they all attached to my `Parser` class. `Parser` is a class to deal with xpath parsing (which is a very **heavily** stuff), I put the `startParse` in `fetchDataFromServer` method within `viewDidLoad` method, and it blocks the UI. It also caused memory leaks.

[image]
This will leak:

```
if (isExisted) {
    NSLog(@"IS EXISTED");
    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithPath:self.filePath];
    [parser startParse];   
    if (parser.returnArray) {
        self.objects = parser.returnArray;
        NSLog(@"self.objcet : %@", self.objects);
        /// CoreData
        //[weakSelf saveData];

        //[weakSelf fetchDataFromCoreData];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
});
```

This doesn't leak:

```
if (isExisted) {
    NSLog(@"IS EXISTED");
    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithPath:self.filePath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [parser startParse];
        if (parser.returnArray) {
            self.objects = parser.returnArray;
            NSLog(@"self.objcet : %@", self.objects);
            /// CoreData
            //[weakSelf saveData];

            //[weakSelf fetchDataFromCoreData];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    });
}
```

Another point: Should I place `[self.tableView reloadData]` into the `dispatch_get_main_queue()`?

Comment: I think issue is with "self.objects". If you want to use any class instance in dispatch_async then you need to first create weak reference of that object and then use it.

Comment: > Another point: Should I place [self.tableView reloadData] into the dispatch_get_main_queue()?
Definitely - yes.